# How to ignore whitespaces and retain special characters only for Numeric

Tags: c#, .net, string, special-characters

I want to remove special characters from a string and need to retain special characters if it appears in-between, before or after any numeric value.

For example,
if my input is `"My   14 "  Apple -  laptop (note-book)  price is $ 900.45 but [I've paid only 900 $"`
then output should be `"My 14 " Apple laptop note-book price is $ 900.45 but I've paid only 900 $"`

I removed extra whitespaces from a string using regex (`var res= str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");`) and now my sentence will have single whitespace between each word.

In addition, I want to

1. Remove all special characters which appears before and after string but should ignore if it appears in-between a string. `(ex: (note-book) will be note-book and I've will be I've)`
2. Ignore set of specified special characters if it appears before, after or in-between a numeric.`(ex: $ 900.45 will be $ 900.45)`

Initially I tried splitting the word using separator and implemented a logic to remove special characters based on numeric or word but it is not working as expected.

```
private static readonly string[] splChars = { "#", "₹", "$", "€", "£", "₽", "¥", ",", "/", "!", "@", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "'", "\"", ";", "_","-", ":", "|", "[", "]", "{", "}" };
char[] separators = { ' ' };
private static readonly string[] splCharsNotAllowedForNumeric = { "/", "!", "@", "^", "&", "(", ")", "'", "\"", ";", "_", "|", "[", "]", "{", "}" };
string[] wrdList = res.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
wrdList = RemoveSpecialCharacters(wrdList).ToArray();
private static List<string> RemoveSpecialCharacters(string[] words)
{
   List<string> cleaned = new List<string>();
   foreach (string word in words)
   {
       var split = word.Split(splChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       var rejoined = string.Join("", split);
       if (IsNumeric(rejoined))
       {
           var numSplit = word.Split(splCharsNotAllowedForNumeric, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           var numRejoined = string.Join("", numSplit);
           cleaned.Add(numRejoined);
       }
       else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(split.FirstOrDefault()))
       {
           cleaned.Add(rejoined);
       }
   }

   return cleaned;  
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: It will be complex logic and definitely will impact the performance of your application.